# Print an Arraylist to RESTful webservices

Tags: java, json, rest, arraylist

first of all, my question would be a bit long but i dont think its complex. But i simply have not clue where the problem could be.

So let me start.

Im trying to print an Arraylist into webpages. I have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "brand": "audi",
    "model": "q8",
    "color": "red",
    "price": "123",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "brand": "audi",
    "model": "r6",
    "color": "sfg",
    "price": "952",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "BMW",
    "model": "IDK",
    "color": "Red",
    "price": "105",
    "available": true
  }
]
```

I read the json file and save the data into an arraylist "carList" with this method

```
try(JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.db)))){
        Gson myGson = new Gson();
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

        JsonArray array = jsonParser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonArray();

        this.carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

        for (JsonElement element : array) {
            Car car = myGson.fromJson(element, Car.class);
            carList.add(car);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My "Car" class has those variables

```
private int id = 0;
private String brand;
private String model;
private String color;
private String price;
private boolean available = true;
```

And when i print my "carList" with this

```
public ArrayList<Car> printAllCars(){
    return carList;
}
```

and this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
ArrayList<Car> printAllCars() {
    return cars.printAllCars();
}
```

I got this with postman
[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAqEq.jpg)

So as you can see, the problem is the price is not printed and "available" is printed as "state".

But when i print in eclipse the price is displayed.
[eclipse result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oUXJ.jpg)

Sorry for my long post, my bad english and my bad code but please help me guys !

Comment: Could you please show `Car` class fully? Probably you forgot getter for `price` field.

Comment: well that was simple ... i did actually forget getter for price. Thanks a lot, i solved both problems.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson looks at `get...()` and `set...()` methods, so don't forget to add these methods or us filed-based serialization.